# MultiCollider chat notification appears after some time I've read the comment

Tags: bug, chat, notifications

I don't know whether this is an actual bug or it's just happening to me, but it never happened before now, as far as I can remember.

What happens is that someone pings me in chat, I read the message because I'm already in the chat room, and the conversation goes on. After a while, I get the red ball notification in the MultiCollider in the Main site (which one is not important for this), only to discover it's a relatively old message that I've already seen and replied to minutes earlier.

What is happening?

Adding some detail from the comments: I am using a computer, not on mobile. When I see the notification, I assume it's about some new event, but the preview makes me realize it's an old chat message.

Comment: Are you on mobile, and if not, do you acknowledge the notification by clearing the bubble directly or by sending new messages?

Comment: @TimStone I'm not on mobile. I'm not sure I got your second question, sorry, but I'll try to answer it: I click on the bubble because I think it's a new notification, but I realize it's about an old chat message.

Comment: When you get a notification in chat, there's a bubble ([example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SU40X.png)) that comes up in the room to tell you of the new message. You can clear it by sending new messages or by clicking it (or pressing escape), but if you don't, the message will eventually show up in your inbox.

Comment: @TimStone The notification appears on the Main site, not in chat. I talked about the MultiCollider (the StackExchange button on the top left).

Comment: Oh, no, I just missed the part where you said that you had indeed replied to the message. Sorry for the confusion. That shouldn't happen then, no.

Comment: @TimStone No problem! :)

Comment: I faced this issue just now, making me curious why it happened... (additional info: I also received the notification on SE mobile app, so perhaps the SE chat server didn't acknowledge when we dismiss the mention, or the packet just got lost in blue? Dunno.)